# Updating Ubuntu 20.04 Server

Tags: server, updates, administration

I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Emby server.  And periodically, I log in via SSH to run "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade" to keep my OS patched.  I also periodically run "sudo apt autoremove" to remove obsolete components.  But when I do the same thing on Ubuntu 20.04 workstation, then launch the "Software" app, it finds obsolete kernel files that it recommends be removed - and I allow it to do that.  My question is - what is the command line equivalent to the function being performed the Ubuntu Software app?  How do I tell Ubuntu server to find and remove obsolete kernels?

Comment: Unattended Upgrades should be automatically uninstalling older kernels and keeping your OS patched (for security vulnerabilities, not bugfixes) without you needing to do anything. The fact that you need to perform such maintenance manually suggests that something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use special script named [`purge-old-kernels`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/purge-old-kernels.1.html) on any machine.

It is a part of [`byobu` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=purge-old-kernels&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any).

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install byobu
```

and then run

```
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

Comment: Than you.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  On my workstations, I had to install the package, but apparently, it comes bundled with Ubuntu server.